# Manual content compression in Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, gzip, mod-deflate

I need a manual compression solution on Apache. My goals:

- Provide gzip-encoded content on my server along with uncompressed.
- Files are pre-compressed.
- Not all files are served compressed. I want to specify these files and the choice isn't type (extension) based.
- Many content-types (custom ones) are served, and new types are showing up from time to time. Also, file extension doesn't determine if it will be compressed or not (**!!!**).
- Keep overhead minimal (the less extra headers, the better).
- Always provide Content-Length header and never send chunked response (this disqualifies `mod_deflate`).

---

## Ideal Functionality

Ideal functionality would work like that:

- Web client asks for file `file.ext`.
- If `file.ext.gz` exists on server:

  - `Content-Encoding` is set to `gzip`.
  - `Content-Type` is set to value of `file.ext` (**!!!**).
  - Server returns `file.ext.gz`.
- Otherwise, `file.ext` is returned.

I tested a number of solutions, [this article](http://www.cravediy.com/59-Simple-gzip-Support-for-Apache-with-mod_rewrite.html) contains a good compilation, but there was always a problem with parts marked with  (**!!!**). I have hundreds of thousands of files and dozens of content types and because of that I'm looking for some automatic solution, without need of adding `ForceType` for each file.

---

## What I tried

### Multiviews

How this works:

- Rename a file `file.ext` to `file.ext.en`
- Create a file `file.ext.gz`
- Configure Apache:

  ```
  Options +MultiViews
  AddEncoding x-gzip .gz
  RemoveType .gz
  ```

Works almost as expected, except it requires the original file (`file.ext`) to not exist and it adds many (useless to me) headers (`TCN`, `Content-Language` and few more) that can't be removed (`Header unset` doesn't remove them).

### Rewrite

How this works:
 - Create `file.ext.gz` file.
 - Configure Apache:

```
<pre>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f
RewriteRule (.*)$ $1.gz [L]
AddEncoding x-gzip .gz

<Files file.ext>
    ForceType my-custom/mime-type
</FilesMatch>
</pre>
```

This works well, but requires a `ForceType` for each compressed file. As I said before, I can't rely on extensions because not all files of certain type will be compressed.

### `mod_deflate`

I didn't investigate it too much, the problem is that if file is too big, then it's split into pieces and sent in chunks and `Content-Length` is not provided. Increasing size of compression buffers can't eliminate this problem.

---

**Is it possible at all to configure Apache to work as I'd liked to?**

I tried to dynamically get `Content-Type` of `file.ext` and set it to `file.ext.gz`, but I didn't find the way how to do this.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve here? mod_deflate would work just fine in most cases, and the little extra CPU overhead is not that big a deal these days, with those beefy servers. What is different in your situation?

Comment: As I described above - mod_deflate doesn't provide Content-Length for big files and divides transfer into chunks. Other thing is that I don't want to compress every file, I want to choose individually.
All this effort is because the client is a mobile app where every CPU cycle and every byte is very valuable.