# Apache server pre compressed javascript

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to make my appache server, server a javascript file which I have compressed my self.
I don't want my javascript to be compressed on the fly for example with mod_deflate or mod_gzip. I have already compress the file my self and I just want to serve it.
Among others I have follow the instructions from this post (which is my current configuration). 
[Manual content compression in Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524907/manual-content-compression-in-apache)
and from 
http://www.cravediy.com/59-Simple-gzip-Support-for-Apache-with-mod_rewrite.html.

I have also tried some other partial solution that I read here and there but I cannot make it work.

Currently my .htaccess configuration is like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f
    RewriteRule (.*\.(js|css))$ $1.gz [L]
</IfModule>
AddEncoding x-gzip .gz
<FilesMatch .*\js.gz >
 ForceType application/x-javascript
</FilesMatch>
```

I have read a lot of solution but they do not work for my inlucding this
[How can I pre-compress files with mod_deflate in Apache 2.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75482/how-can-i-pre-compress-files-with-mod-deflate-in-apache-2-x/24593023#24593023)
I dont know what I am doing wrong and I have not get an answer.
Besides I think the above solutionshould work without Mutliviews because it use rewrite to rename the requested files.
Can someon please helpe me with the correct configuration? 
For testing purpose I have jquery.min.js and jquery.min.js.gs

The file that server is not the compressed one but the uncompressed.

I am hosted on plesk 11.5 using centos 6.5 and apache 2.2.15.

I have tried lots of thinks but I can not make it work. Any help would be appreciated

you can test my page here
http://www.elpidajob.gr

thanks for yout time.

Comment: Is there any reason why `mod_deflate` won't do the job here?

Comment: As far as I understan mod_defalte compress content on the fly. I want to have my files precompressed and kust serve them

Comment: Why is it necessary to have them pre-compressed? The overhead is so minimal it's barely worth worrying about. You'll be network bound before you're CPU bound.